# IBoutlet is connected in .m file but IB did not highlight it

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iboutlet, outlet

[image: screenshot]

I have some doubt about my xcode. After I connect an IBoutlet in .m file, I mouse up on the round spot like the screenshot above. But IB did not highlight the UILabel which is connected as before. what happened? my xcode version is 7.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this whenever XCode misbehaves and clean build doesn't solve the issue

1)  Window → Projects
2) find the current project
3) delete the derived data
4) close Xcode and rebuild your project

Comment: Thanks.I tried what u said, but it still did not work.."rebuild ",does it mean reopening this project?